# Hibernate IllegalArgumenetException on enum column

Tags: sql, hibernate, enums

In my item table, I have an enum column to describe the status of that item:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="status")
private ItemStatus status;
```

Then when I the item is added to cart, I want to list all the item in cart with this query:

```
select i.* from item as i inner joint cart as c on i.item_id = c.item_id
where c.owner_id=:owner_id group by i.item_id
```

The result on the above is returned as I expected. However I would like also to get more details on the item's owner so I change the query to:

```
select i.*, u.* from item as i inner join cart as c on i.item_id = c.item_id
inner join customer as u on i.owner_id = u.customer_id
where c.owner_id = :owner_id group by i.item_id, u.customer_id

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryname);
List<Object[]> result = query.addEntity(Item.class)
                                .addEntity(Customer.class)
                                .setParameter("owner_id", owner_id)
                                .list();
```

With the second query I got unknown name value for enum class on the status column. I wonder why there is exception on the first query but the second one. And what is the correct way to fetch the enum column in hibernate?

This is my enum class

```
public enum ItemStatus {
ACTIVE, UNAVAILABLE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you also add Cart entity?

```
List<Object[]> result = query.addEntity(Item.class)
                              .addEntity(Cart.class)
                                .addEntity(Customer.class)
                                .setParameter("owner_id", owner_id)
                                .list();
```

Comment: I only want to get the item info and the owner info of that item, so why do I need to add Cart entity? I tried to run the second query on pgAdmin and the result is as I expected. So I think I applied hibernate SQLquery uncorrectly